# Ordenar una lista en Python

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un programa donde le pregunte al usuario nombres y este los guarde y ordene alfabéticamente.

Esto es lo que tengo ahora:

```py
    names = input("What are the names? ") 
    print(names) 
    sorted_names = sorted(names) 
    print(sorted_names)
```

pero cuando corro el programa sale esto

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'M', 'M', 'Z', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'i', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'p', 'r', 't', 't']
```

ordena cada letra alfabéticamente.

¿Cómo hacer que los nombres salgan completos y ordenados alfabéticamente?

Comment: ¿Como asumes que el usuario va a ingresar cada nombre? ¿Separados por comas `,` por ejemplo?

Comment: si lo intente poniendo comas pero el resultado es el mismo agarra cada letra de cada nombre y las ordena alfabeticamente

Comment: me gustaria saber como es la cadena que ingresas.. pero estas usando la funcion sorted mal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que al aplicar `sorted` a la cadena conviertes  el string al completo en una lista, es decir, cada carácter pasa a ser un elemento de una lista ordenada.

Debes crear una lista en la que cada nombre sea un elemento y sobre ella aplicar el método de ordenamiento. Para ello usa el método `str.split`:

```
names = input("What are the names? ")
sorted_names = sorted(names.split())
print(sorted_names)
```

Esto es si separas los nombres con espacios, en caso contrario pásale a `split` el separador que desee usar, por ejemplo para usar una coma `names.split(",")`.

En caso de que quieras ordenar sin tener sensibilidad a mayúsculas (pero sin modificar el string original) puedes usar el argumento `key`:

```
names = input("What are the names? ")
sorted_names = sorted(names.split(),  key=lambda x: x.lower())
print(sorted_names)
```

Comment: oh ya lo puse y funciono muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Si el usuarios pone los nombres seguido, separando por coma puedes hacer así:

```
names = input("What are the names? ")
sorted_names = sorted(names.split(", "))
print(sorted_names)
```

si es asi, puedes solucionarlo de esa manera, sino replantéatelo la pregunta.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes optar por un bucle *while* que agrega nombres a una lista infinitamente hasta que escribes una "palabra clave" en este caso "Imprimir".

Cuando ingresas "Imprimir" la lista se ordena debido al comando .sort() y se imprime.

```
nombre = input("Ingrese un nombre: ")
Lista = []
while nombre != "Imprimir":
    Lista.append(nombre)
    nombre = input("Ingrese otro nombre: ")

Lista.sort()
print(Lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que input en Python lee la entrada como una cadena de caracteres, y al utilizar sorted, estás ordenando los caracteres individualmente en lugar de ordenar los nombres completos. Para solucionarlo, puedes dividir la cadena de entrada en una lista de nombres antes de ordenarla.

```py
# Pedir al usuario que ingrese nombres separados por comas
names_input = input("Ingresa los nombres separados por comas: ")

# Dividir la cadena de entrada en una lista de nombres
names_list = names_input.split(',')

# Eliminar espacios en blanco alrededor de cada nombre
names_list = [name.strip() for name in names_list]

# Imprimir la lista de nombres sin ordenar
print("Nombres ingresados:", names_list)

# Ordenar alfabéticamente la lista de nombres
sorted_names = sorted(names_list)

# Imprimir la lista de nombres ordenada alfabéticamente
print("Nombres ordenados:", sorted_names)
```